# UI hang During the Service

Tags: android, service

I am starting an service on a context menu click. but during the service UI hanged and it showing ANR.

I am using a thread in which i am calling the service.

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    serviceThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(Syncspace.this,syncService.class);
            new Bundle();
            startService(i);
        }
    });
    serviceThread.start();

    return false;
}
```

and until task not complete UI hanged . plz help

Comment: Could there be someplace else on the UI thread that you are doing something to make it not responsive?

Comment: in the service i am only retrieving the values from database. and uploading/downloading file to cloud.

Comment: If you look at logcat it should tell you more detail about where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

numerous works on the issue in the docs state to do as much as possible in worker or background  thread for which AsyncTask is the obvious base class along with AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter and  AbstractInputMethodService also have appealing design choices

1] note you likely will have to start the thread with the code in main
2] the exact names use subordinate to what the class does

[Multitasking the Android Way](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/04/multitasking-android-way.html)

Comment: But using AsyncTask is just a way to abstract out that you are doing it in a different thread, which is what the OP is doing, so it should be working. There is something we are not being told as to the actual problem.